# how can i record maximum amount of memory used over time in a linux server

Tags: linux, performance, memory

I plan to launch an app, and plan to set its available memory optimistically high (it's a VPS).  How can I figure out, say looking a month later, what it's maximum usage over that time was, i.e. if it ever came near to swapping memory?  Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Comment: Which virtualization platform are you running? If you're using OpenVZ or Virtuozzo, it's as easy as looking in `/proc/user_beancounters`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's the old standby, sar (sysstat/sa1).  It can give you all sorts of useful statistics including memory and cpu utilization, disk io, etc.  It's stable, run as a cronjob, and available for pretty much every linux distro.

Answer (score 3):

Install a munin server, and run a munin client on the virtual instance.  It will log memory usage and a number of other useful statistists over time.

Answer (score 0):

[collectd](http://collectd.org/) is a plugin-based system statistics collection daemon. I believe the [Memory](http://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:Memory) plugin would fill the need.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be running atop.